# Redirection based on data in mysql table

Tags: java, android

So now i have registration form and after registration you can successfully login and after successfully login it redirects you to a new page - activity in android app. I will make different activities (pages). I want redirect based on informations user gave with registration.

Example: User needs to insert his/her name, surname, age, username and password. 
Let's say we have different activites (pages) based on age of user.
So when he/she login successfully with correct username and password (and his/her age is 18), she/he is redirect to a activity 18.java.
or when he/she login successfully with correct username and password (and his/her age is 20), she/he is redirect to a activity 20.java.

How to do that?

For now my code is sth like that:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);


        if(result.contentEquals("login success !!!!! Welcome user")) {

            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, 18.class));

        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wrong Username or Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }
```

it works fine but only for redirection to the same activity 18.class.

I'm using mysql table.

Registration php is:

```
<?php 

require "conn.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$link_address = "http://10.0.2.2/login.php";

$mysql_qry = "insert into employee_data (name, surname, age, username, password) values ('$name','$surname','$age','$username','$password');";


if($conn->query($mysql_qry)=== TRUE) {
echo 'You have been successfully registered. <a href="'.$link_address.'">Link</a>';

}
else {
echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

and login:

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from employee_data where username like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "login success !!!!! Welcome user";
}
else {
echo "login not success";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the basic issue. What is the problem that you're facing?

Comment: Well, now it redirects u after login to the page 18.java but i need that if you are 20 years old (which is in mysql table near your username and password - u gave me this informations with register form) that it redirects you to activity named 20.java

Comment: you can pass user age in AsynTask and do check in onPostExecute based on user age and start activity accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition of login success in your php code, you need to do some changes.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
/*Since login is successful, you must get the age of the user associated with the email address from sql query and then echo **login success !!!!! Welcome user {age}** */
}
```

And in your java code, modify it accordingly. Check if the age is 18, instantiate the 18.class intent. Else if 20, then the 20.class intent.

Hope you get the basic idea here?